# Can C# natively talk to Websphere and call wsadmin commands?

Tags: c#, websphere

I'm writing a small c# console application that needs to interogate Websphere Application Server ND (6.1) to retrieve a list of installed apps.

I can easily do this from the command line using the wsadmin command, but don't really want to launch wsadmin from my c# app.

Is there a way to natively get c# to talk to Websphere and get this sort of information ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wsadmin is just a scripting interface for [JMX](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/topic/com.ibm.websphere.javadoc.doc/web/mbeanDocs/index.html) and everything you can do with it can be done with RMI and SOAP. For C# users that means querying for [Management Beans](https://ws-jmx-connector.dev.java.net/) via SOAP.

However there are no turn-key solutions available. What has been suggested before has been at least taking a look at the ws-jmx-connector and implementing your own library. You could probably easier just capture one of those queries with ie. SoapUI and replay the SOAP calls. This probably means too much work and that's probably also why there are no ready solutions.

Also, you could just read the XML files that describe the (properly) installed WebSpehre Application Server applications. That is probably much easier, and works just fine. Take a look at the server profile directory. You should see a directory called *config*, then under it *cells*, *your management cell's name* and under that you will find XML files that actually contain every setting you see in the management console. They are well parseable by the standard .NET libraries and a few of those will contain application lists. Take a look at serverindex.xml for instance.